# What is the meaning of "Know not what became of him "?

Tags: meaning

Ados, a novice, saying about his master William.

> I never saw him again and **know not what became of him** but I pray
>   always that God received his soul and forgave.

What is the meaning of " Know not what became of him " in above sentence?

Comment: He doesn't know what happened to his master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify matters, I will trim out most of the sentence and just look at this:

> I know not what became of him.

(The difference between this and what you asked about is that I have included the subject, "I".)

## I know not…

In modern English, if we want to say the negative of a verb, we almost always have to rephrase it as "to do [infinitive]" first. The "not" then goes after the "do".

> I **ate** the cake.
>
> I **did eat** the cake.
>
> I **did not eat** the cake.

However, this was not always true. In old-fashioned use, it was acceptable to negate a verb directly by putting "not" after it (or after its object), without rephrasing to use "to do" first.

> I **ate** the cake.
>
> I **ate not** the cake.

Nowadays, this old-fashioned style is sometimes used deliberately in literary situations.

> I **know** what became of him.
>
> I **know not** what became of him.

## …what became of him.

"What becomes of [someone]" is another way of saying "what happens to [someone]". It is also a little bit old-fashioned.

Unlike just "happens", this implies a fairly permanent result; not necessarily death, but certainly a change in the person's long-term situation. In this case, though, it does mean death: "I pray that God received his soul" means "I believe he died (and hope that he went to heaven)".

> I know not what became of him.
>
> I do not know how he spent the rest of his life or how he died.

Answer (score 0):

*X not* = *I do not X*

> I never saw him again and know not what became of him ...
>
> I never saw him again and do not know what became of him ...

Saying *X not* lends a literary-ish quality to the sentence.